# Material-Table detect hover on row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am using React material-table (https://material-table.com).
Can I detect when a row is hovered?

I need some property like `onRowClick` but for `hover`:

```
<MaterialTable icons={{ Filter: () => 
    <SearchIcon className={classes.searchIcon} /> 
    }} columns={[ ... ]} data={this.props.data} options={{ ... }} 
    onRowClick={(event, rowData) => this.handleOpen(event, rowData)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand that correctly, but I think you are looking for `onMouseEnter`. You can pass in custom components, even for the `row`'s. You can then listen for the mouseenter event on them.

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events

Comment: onMouseEnter is not a valid property of Material-Table. I would like to avoid the overriding because it causes a lot of another issues.

Comment: @Lilly8881 Material-Table doesn't have a built-in listener for mouse enters, so I'm pretty sure overriding is your only option. You can kinda "extend" the default `Row` component like this I believe: 

`const MyTable = props => {
  return <MaterialTable
    components={{
      Row: rowProps => <MTableBodyRow {...rowProps} onMouseEnter={eventHandler} />
    }}
    ... more material table props
  />;
}`